# Is it possible to generate ServiceStack DTOs from an OpenApi specification?

Tags: servicestack, dto, openapi

I have a 3rd party API I need to use and it provides an Open API specification. Is it possible to generate ServiceStack DTOs from the specification for use with the standard `JsonServiceClient` or `JsonHttpClient`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [ServiceStack’s Add Reference feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) is generated from ServiceStack’s richer internal metadata, it’s not possible to generate the same Request/Response and DTO types from an Open API spec directly.